Nginx Proxy Manager "502 Bad Gateway- openresty"
I've recently set up NPM for some servers on my backend and everything seems to be working just fine for most except for a couple servers that seem to return a "502 Bad Gateway" errors even when I'm sure the scheme is correct and and the port is active.
When I try to execute a curl command from within my docker container, it works just fine and the server responds.
Here's the error I managed to get from the error log: "[error] 667#667: *1150 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00042E:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert protocol version:SSL alert number 70) while SSL handshaking to upstream,"
Any ideas how to fix this? I've hit a dead end. Thank you.
I tried to change the resolution from an IP Address one to an FQDN one by modifying the "hosts" file on my reverse proxy server since I noticed that when using the IP Address, my server returns a "404 Not Found" error.

Have you verified that SSL is working upstream?

Yes, running a "curl "command or an "openssl s_client" one shows that it's working and the connection is successful

What I tried to do so far is try a handshake using the two versions of TLS (v1.2 and v1.3) and what I've noticed compared to the other servers, the server I'm having an issue with only accepts a TLSv1.3 handshake. Taking this a step further, I added a line within my NPM config to specify the usage of TLSv1.3 "ssl_protocols  TLSv1.3;" yet it didn't work.
